comment reply in wordpress
I'm trying to build a theme and a part of the single page doesn't work and that is the comment reply part.
I use  wp_comment_list for setting type & style & callback function.
                <div class="comments">
                    <h2 class="comments-title"> نظرات</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_list_comments([
                            'type' => 'comment',
                            'style' => 'ul',
                            'callback' => 'calb_comment'
                        ], get_comments(['post_id' => get_the_ID() ])); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

and calb_comment function for callback contains comment_reply_link
function calb_comment($comment, $args, $depth)
{
    ?>
                                    <li class="comment">
                                    <article class="comment-body">
                                        <footer class="comment-meta">
                                            <div class="comment-author ">
                                                <?php echo get_avatar($comment, '128'); ?>
                                                <?php printf( __( '<b class="fn">%s</b> <span class="says">says:</span>' ), get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
                                            </div><!-- .comment-author -->

                                            <div class="comment-metadata">
                                                <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
                                                <?php
                                                /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                                                printf( 
                                                    __('%1$s at %2$s'), 
                                                    get_comment_date('l,Y,m'),  
                                                    get_comment_time() 
                                                ); ?>
                                                </a>
                                            </div><!-- .comment-metadata -->

                                        </footer><!-- .comment-meta -->

                                        <div class="comment-content">
                                        <?php comment_text(); ?>
                                        </div><!-- .comment-content -->

                                        <div class="reply">
                                            <?php 
                                            comment_reply_link( 
                                                array_merge( 
                                                    $args, 
                                                        array( 
                                                            'add_below' => 'comment',
                                                            'depth'      => $depth,
                                                            'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']
                                                        ) 
                                                )
                                            ); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </article><!-- .comment-body -->
                                </li><!-- #comment-## -->
    <?php
}

and comment_form for building a form for comment and reply that contains some inputs and a button
                <div class="comment-respond">
                    <h3 class="comment-reply-title mb-lg-5 mb-4">
                        پیام بگذارید
                    </h3>
                    <?php comment_form([
                        'fields' => [
                            
                            'author' => '<div class="row"><div class=" col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" placeholder="نام*" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>',
                            'email' => '<div class=" col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="ایمیل*" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>',
                            'url' => '<div class=" col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="وب سایت" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div></div>'
                        ],
                        'comment_field' => '<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <textarea name="comment" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="نظر*" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>',
                        'title_reply' => '',
                        'submit_field' => '<div class="text-center mt-md-5">%1$s %2$s</div>',
                        'submit_button' => '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" >ارسال</button>'
                    ]); ?>
                </div>

